# Mass action for tranfering products with default values. Magento 1.8

Tags: adminhtml, product-attribute, products, websites, massaction

I am able to transfer a single product between stores and choose default values

[image]

The code doing this is the following:

```
<?php if($this->getWebsites() && !$this->hasWebsite($_website->getId())): ?>
    <span class="website-<?php echo $_website->getId() ?>-select" style="display:none">
    <?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('(Copy data from: %s)', $this->getChooseFromStoreHtml($_store)) ?>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But i cannot do the same with multiple products at a time??? I have pasted the same code into

```
adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/action/websites.phtml
```

But it does not work!

[image]

Please help! It would mean so much too me if I could solve this problem as I'm newly employed and don't know much about magento yet (wow it's big and hard to understand!) - Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this extension https://github.com/magento-hackathon/CopyStoreData 
and modified

```
Model/Observer.php  
public function controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save()
```

by adding

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->addProducts($copyToIds, $helper->getProductIds());
```

And that's it, we're able to mass copy products and their information between stores!

This extension probably could be used as well: https://github.com/avstudnitz/StoreViewCopy